# QR code reader for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Windows Phone app and I need a simple QR code reader. I'm following [a tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richmac/archive/2011/11/07/creating-a-qr-code-reader-app-for-windows-phone-7.aspx).

I did everything, and now I must add

```
private PhotoCamera camera;
```

But there is always this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'PhotoCamera' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you added using :

```
using Microsoft.Devices;
```

because `PhotoCamera` class is available from `Microsoft.Devices` namespace. Otherwise you'll need to use fully-qualified class name :

```
private Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera camera;
```

Comment: Great. Don't forget to accept this answer to confirm the problem solved this way :)

Answer (score 2):

The required using is probably missing:

```
using Microsoft.Devices;
```